# How to graph with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, chart.js

I was, as part of a training program in Paraguay, trying to integrate a function graph into a javascript script. Browsing the web I found an option which doesn't quite work for me so I throw the graph inside the page. I'm sharing my code for a basal hydration calculator and the javascript script I've been trying to get the graph to give me:

**Html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Calculadora de hidratación</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css" />
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <div id="calculadora">
        <h2>Hidratación Basal</h2>
        <input type="number" id="peso" placeholder="Indicar peso en kilogramos" />
        <button onclick="calcular(); mostrarGrafica(parseInt(document.getElementById('peso').value))" </button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <p1>
          <output id="Resultado"></output>
        </p1>
      </div>
      <div id="descripcion">
        <h3>¿Cómo se calcula?</h3>
        <ul>
          <li>De 0kg a 10kg, se calcula 100cc por cada kilo.</li>
          <li>Se suman 50cc por cada kilo de peso por arriba de 10kg, hasta 20kg</li>
          <li>De 20kg y hasta 30kg, se suman 20cc por cada kilo adicional</li>
          <li>De 30kg para arriba, se determina mediante la superficie corporal del paciente </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <canvas id="grafica" width="400" height="200"></canvas>
    </div>
    <script src="./index-calculadoralucas.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Javascript**

```js
function calcular() {
    var number = parseInt(document.getElementById("peso").value);
    var resultado = document.getElementById("Resultado");
    if (number >= 0 && number <= 10) {
        resultado.innerHTML = "La cantidad necesaria es: " + (number * 100 / 16) + "cc/hr";
    } else if (number > 10 && number <= 20) {
        resultado.innerHTML = "La cantidad necesaria es: " + (((number - 10) * 50 + 1500) / 16) + "cc/hr";
    } else if (number > 20 && number <= 30) {
        resultado.innerHTML = "La cantidad necesaria es: " + (((number - 20) * 20 + 1500) / 16) + "cc/hr";
    } else if (number > 30) {
        resultado.innerHTML = "La cantidad necesaria es: " + (((((number * 4 + 7) / (number + 90)) * 2000) / 24).toFixed(2)) + "cc/hr";
    } else {
        resultado.innerHTML = "Ingrese un número válido";
    }
}

function mostrarGrafica(peso) {
    var ctx = document.getElementById('grafica').getContext('2d');
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            labels: ['0', '10', '20', '30'],
            datasets: [{
                label: 'Función de cálculo',
                data: calcularFuncion(peso),
                borderColor: '#e50914',
                borderWidth: 2,
                fill: false
            }]
        },
        options: {
            scales: {
                x: {
                    type: 'linear',
                    position: 'bottom'
                },
                y: {
                    min: 0
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

It was intended that, as the user enters a weight, the script identifies the function to be calculated in a two-dimensional coordinate graph. It was not a necessary requirement within the program but I found it interesting that, according to the formula provided for patients weighing more than 30 kg, basal hydration tended to a number equal to 333.33 when the limit approached infinity.

Comment: and where is `calcularFuncion()` defined?

Comment: I'm a bit new to code. It is possible for the code to identify the function defined within the domain that the user grants and graph the function itself, also locating the point? That is, if the user, for example, indicates 32 kg, the graph would be that of the function y=c*(4x+7)/(x+90), otherwise, if the user indicates 5 kg, the graph is that of y=100*x/16

Comment: Then you'll have to compute an array of points for each case, something like in [this version](https://jsfiddle.net/69p3x7gf/).

Answer (score 1):

You code had so many problems.  You missed the calcularFuncion, your button did not had any text inside it. The style.css is also missing. This code is the corrected version of yours with a calcularFuncion that maybe you want to change it.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Calculadora de hidratación</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css" />
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <div id="calculadora">
                <h2>Hidratación Basal</h2>
                <input type="number" id="peso" placeholder="Indicar peso en kilogramos"/>
                <button onclick="calcular(); mostrarGrafica(parseInt(document.getElementById('peso').value))">x
                </button>
            </div>
            <div>
                <p1><output id="Resultado"></output></p1>
            </div>
            <div id="descripcion">
                <h3>¿Cómo se calcula?</h3>
                <ul>
                    <li>De 0kg a 10kg, se calcula 100cc por cada kilo.</li>
                    <li>Se suman 50cc por cada kilo de peso por arriba de 10kg, hasta 20kg</li>
                    <li>De 20kg y hasta 30kg, se suman 20cc por cada kilo adicional</li>
                    <li>De 30kg para arriba, se determina mediante la superficie corporal del paciente
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <canvas id="grafica" width="400" height="200"></canvas>
        </div>
        <script >
    function calcularFuncion(peso) {
    var values = [];
    for (var i = 0; i <= 30; i++) {
    if (i >= 0 && i <= 10) {
    values.push(i * 100 / 16);
    } else if (i > 10 && i <= 20) {
    values.push(((i - 10) * 50 + 1500) / 16);
    } else if (i > 20 && i <= 30) {
    values.push(((i - 20) * 20 + 1500) / 16);
    } else if (i > 30) {
    values.push(((((i * 4 + 7) / (i + 90)) * 2000) / 24).toFixed(2));
    }
    }
    return values;
    }
    function calcular(){
        var number = parseInt(document.getElementById("peso").value); 
        var resultado = document.getElementById("Resultado");
    if (number >= 0 && number <= 10) {
        resultado.innerHTML = "La cantidad necesaria es: " + (number * 100 / 16) + "cc/hr";
    } else if (number > 10 && number <= 20) {
        resultado.innerHTML = "La cantidad necesaria es: " + (((number - 10) * 50 + 1500) / 16) + "cc/hr";
    } else if (number > 20 && number <= 30) {
        resultado.innerHTML = "La cantidad necesaria es: " + (((number - 20) * 20 + 1500) / 16) + "cc/hr";
    } else if (number > 30) {
        resultado.innerHTML = "La cantidad necesaria es: " + (((((number * 4 + 7) / (number + 90)) * 2000) / 24).toFixed(2)) + "cc/hr";
    } else {
        resultado.innerHTML = "Ingrese un número válido";
    }
    }
    function mostrarGrafica(peso) {
    var ctx = document.getElementById('grafica').getContext('2d');
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            labels: ['0', '10', '20', '30'],
            datasets: [{
                label: 'Función de cálculo',
                data: calcularFuncion(peso),
                borderColor: '#e50914',
                borderWidth: 2,
                fill: false
            }]
        },
        options: {
            scales: {
                x: {
                    type: 'linear',
                    position: 'bottom'
                },
                y: {
                    min: 0
                }
            }
        }
    }); 

    } 

    </script> 
    </body>
    </html>
```